# ggplot troubleshoot: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24): x, y, fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample data:

```
> dput(droplevels(data[1:50, ]))
    structure(list(QtySold = c(3L, -1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, -1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 30L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 
20L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 30L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 90L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 
15L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 1L, -4L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, -1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 30L, 2L, 12L, 20L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 
4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 1L, -1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
8L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 15L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
10L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 
12L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 24L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 
-1L), PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Handpieces", 
"PRIVATE LABEL", "SUNDRY"), class = "factor"), MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY = structure(c(23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 16L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 21L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 4L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 11L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 21L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 12L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 13L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 
21L, 21L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 11L), .Label = c("AIR ", 
"AML ", "ANS ", "ASE ", "ASP ", "B&D ", "BLE ", "C&P ", "CBL ", 
"CEM ", "CMP ", "CRN ", "END ", "FNP ", "GYP ", "HND ", "IMP ", 
"INS ", "OTH ", "P&P ", "PRE ", "RTC ", "SME ", "UCL ", "XRY "
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the relevant code

```
     > newdf = subset(data, select = c(QtySold, PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR, MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY))
> sample = newdf %>% 
+   filter(QtySold < 0) %>%
+   group_by(PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR,MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY) %>%
+   summarise(returns = sum(QtySold)) %>%
+   spread(PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR,returns, fill=0) %>%
+   mutate(total_returns = `PRIVATE LABEL` + SUNDRY + Handpieces,
+          PercentageReturn_PL = round(`PRIVATE LABEL`/ total_returns*100,1))
> sample %>%
+               group_by(PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR) %>%
+               summarise(count=n()) %>%
+               mutate(percent= paste0(round(count/sum(count)*100,1),'%'))
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR` is unknown
```

My scenario:

- List item
- I have a data set of three products: Sundry, Handpieces and Private Label.
- I filtered the data set based on (QtySold < 0) category and group the new one based on "PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR" and 
  "MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY".
- I want to see the percentage of returned items which belong to Private Label category. My code has a mutate command with a new column "PercentageReturn_PL".
- Finally, when I am done with the math, I want to plot this whole thing with the MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY on the Y-axis and the stacked barplot show the segments of percentage break down for three products within one MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY.

How can I fix this error?

```
> sample %>%
+               group_by(PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR) %>%
+               summarise(count=n()) %>%
+               mutate(percent= paste0(round(count/sum(count)*100,1),'%'))
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR` is unknown
```

Comment: I can't run your code.  For example, when you filter your dataset to only rows where the quantity sold is less than 0 there are no rows left.  But also you refer to `PRODUCT_SUB_LINES_DESCR` in the plotting code but as far as I can tell that variable would no longer be in the wide dataset.  For troubleshooting this error I'd recommend doing the data manipulation in a separate step from the plotting so you can explore the dataset.

Comment: @aosmith I don't get what you suggested.

Comment: If people keep down-voting, how do we learn? Downvoting keeps learners from asking questions. If you have some thoughts on improvements, please speak! Don't be passive aggressive. Thank you!

Comment: Right now I can't tell if the problem is in ggplot or in the data manipulation code.  I'm proposing that you do your data manipulation in one step and save the object (i.e., data2 = data %>% filter(...) %>% summarise(...`) so you can take a look at it. You may be able to figure out the problem that way.  For example, maybe `PRODUCT_SUB_LINES_DESCR` isn't in that dataset but is in your environment and so is causing the plotting error.

Comment: @aosmith Hey, can we join in a chat room, please? I really need help!

Comment: Also,  please explain the problem. You ask *"How can I fix this error?"*, but that is the only information you give about "the error". Which line produces the error? What does the error message say?

Comment: @Gregor I am looking into the return quantities. My company quotes that into negative values and the positive ones are the one we sell and nobody returns. I need to know: Ok I have 3 product categories and each of them has returned items. I wanna look at the return rate for the House Brand since I wanna invest more in the House Brand product so I am still learning the data set.

Comment: @Gregor The error is here: geom_bar(aes(x=PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR,y=total_returns, 
               fill = PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR),stat='identity', show.legend = F).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172992/discussion-between-adam-ralphus-and-gregor).

Comment: @Gregor I do not need 16 of them right now but I do need all of them for my decision tree analysis!

Comment: @Gregor I posted a new sample data set.

Comment: Okay. Data looks good. I'm trying to help you learn how to debug things like this yourself, and how to ask a good question. You still haven't mentioned *what  the error message says*. Please edit that into your question. Transforming data and piping it straight into your plot makes it hard to debug, because you don't actually see the data you are giving to `ggplot`. Save the data post-transformation as a new object, maybe `data_wide`. Look at it, and see if the error makes sense. Don't bury useful information like which line produces the error down in the comments, edit it into your question.

Comment: @Gregor Hi Greg, I did edit my post. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you `spread` out a column and then tried to use it. Also a lot of extra stuff going on in the graph.

Here's a way to get the percent of returns that are PRIVATE LABEL by major category:

```
sample_long = 
    newdf %>%
    filter(QtySold < 0) %>%
    group_by(MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY) %>%
    summarize(returns = sum(QtySold),
                        percent_returns_pl = sum(QtySold[PRODUCT_SUB_LINE_DESCR == "PRIVATE LABEL"]) / returns)
```

And then we can plot easily:

```
ggplot(
    sample_long,
    aes(x = MAJOR_CATEGORY_KEY, y = percent_returns_pl)
) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percent_returns_pl)), vjust = -0.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

It's a boring plot with sample data, should be much more interesting with the full data.